# How do I get cume_dist (or percentile) of a value from one column in another?

Tags: postgresql, dbt, percentile

I'm using postgresql in DBT, so either a postgresql or a DBT solution is viable.

I have a table with fundamentally 4 columns, `target, question, value, current`

I can get the percentile (`cume_dist`) of the value with:

```
(cume_dist() over (partition by question order by value)) * 100 as percentile
```

However, targets where the current is zero aren't in the  comparison. I need the percentile of them, but they aren't in the "dataset" (they are historical data from the same targets, so they aren't current, but I need the percentile as if they were current)

However, I effectively need the percentile of every value, within the subset of values where `current` is 1.

ETA:
I see in the documentation that `cume_dist` can take args, but I haven't found any documentation on what those args represent or how to use them...

Comment: Where do you see mention of `cume_dist()` taking arguments in the documentation?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-HYPOTHETICAL-TABLE

Comment: it appears that the argument only works with constants, not a column...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Re-implement cume_dist()**

As far as I know, there is no way to do this with the existing `cume_dist()` function, but it's pretty easy to implement the same functionality without `cume_dist()`.

The [postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-window.html) say `cume_dist()`

> Returns the cumulative distribution, that is (number of partition rows
> preceding or peers with current row) / (total partition rows). The
> value thus ranges from 1/N to 1.

Here is how I set up my demo data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  target VARCHAR,
  question VARCHAR,
  value INT,
  current BOOL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
('alice',   'number of hats', 7, true),
('alice',   'number of hats', 6, false),
('alice',   'number of hats', 3, false),
('bob',     'number of hats', 4, true),
('charles', 'number of hats', 9, true),
('david',   'number of hats', 0, true),
('erin',    'number of hats', 4, true),
('alice',   'number of fingers', 10, true),
('bob',     'number of fingers', 10, true),
('charles', 'number of fingers',  9, true),
('charles', 'number of fingers', 10, false),
('david',   'number of fingers', 10, true),
('erin',    'number of fingers', 10, true);
```

and here is how to do that same thing (rows preceding) / (total rows) without `cume_dist()` and with some added logic to exclude rows where that aren't current:

```sql
SELECT
  target,
  question,
  value,
  current,
  (
    -- this is the count of partition rows preceding this row
    SELECT COUNT(1)
    FROM my_table AS inner_table
    WHERE
      inner_table.question = outer_table.question AND
      current = true AND
      inner_table.value <= outer_table.value
  )::real / (
    -- this is the total number of rows for this question
    SELECT COUNT(1)
    FROM my_table AS inner_table
    WHERE
      inner_table.question = outer_table.question AND
      current = true
  )::real * 100.0 AS percentile
FROM my_table AS outer_table;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/AuT6NYOa) is a fiddle link with this query

Comment: presumably the 2nd AS inner_table should be outer_table?

Comment: @BrianPostow No. `outer_table` is the one outside a sub-query, and `inner_table` is the table that only exists inside the sub-query. There are 2 sub-queries, each with an `inner_table`. If you prefer, you could label them separately (ex: `inner_table_a` and `inner_table_b`)